# $n\phi(n)$ with $\phi$ the totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

How do I prove this theorem I found on the Wikipedia article about Euler's totient function:

$$\frac{1}{2}n\phi(n)=\sum_{\begin{matrix}1\leq k \leq n \\ \gcd(k,n)=1\end{matrix}} k$$

I am aware, that $$\phi(n)=\sum_{\begin{matrix}1\leq k \leq n \\ \gcd(k,n)=1\end{matrix}} 1$$

but I am not sure what to do from here...

Comment: You will need theorems of Dirichlet convolution.

Comment: @orion No, you won't.

Comment: Oh. I foolishly took a blind and longer road.

Comment: Note, it is only true if $n>1.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n\\(k,n)=1}} (n-k) = \sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n\\(k,n)=1}} k$$

Thus:

$$\begin{align}n\phi(n) &= n \sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n\\(k,n)=1}} 1\\ &= \sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n\\(k,n)=1}} n \\&= \sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n\\(k,n)=1}}(n-k) + \sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n\\(k,n)=1}} k \\&= 2\sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n\\(k,n)=1}} k\end{align}$$

---

Note, the first equality is only true for $n>1$, since when $n=1$ you have that $(1,1)=1$ so the left side is $1-1$ and the right side is $1.$

Comment: well that was easy. Thank you.